# jQuery Selectmenu Plugin - Can't Hide Selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the "Selectmenu" plugin created by Filament Group.  I can't provide a hyperlink because I haven't posted enough on Stackoverflow to use more than 2 hyperlinks.

I have 2 selectboxes; one listing s/w (tool) and one for tool version. I want to be able to select a tool, show the tool version selectbox and write version-specific data to the screen.  This is working fine as long as the user does not select another tool before selecting a version.

When the user selects a tool w/out selecting a version, the previous version selectbox does not hide.  For instance if the user select "cgs" then the "cgs versions" selectbox shows.  But if the user does not select a version and instead selects another tool, say "dpss", the "dpss versions" selectbox appears but the "cgs versions" selectbox does not hide.

It should be as simple as this, which does not work:

```
$("select:not(#cgs)").hide();
```

I am placing it inside the If statement that checks for the tool version.

**Javascript Pastie:** http://pastie.org/2695842

**HTML Pastie:** http://pastie.org/2685522

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Live demo (using the above-linked jQuery and HTML): [at JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Na9Wq/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Na9Wq/).

Comment: Post your code *here*, and then link to your live demo *or* a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net), which allows us to play with the code in-situ.

Comment: I look at your code and I'm assuming that you want to hide all select elements *except* for `#tool`, and then reveal the versions menu for that specific tool? But that doesn't seem to be what you're asking in your question...I've come up with something (http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Na9Wq/1/), but...it feels like you're hoping for more?

Comment: David, thanks for the help.  You are right in what I want.  I opened up a jsFiddle account and entered data but it is nothing like what I see on the screen.  Part of the problem is I am using the Selecmenu plugin ([link](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) and I don't see how I can use the .js and .css files for the plugin.  I actually have the code working w/out using the Selectmenu plugin, although much more verbose than yours.

Comment: I not sure why I can't use "$("select:not(#cgs)").hide();" to hide all other version selectboxes when I test for the selected tool. This is only an issue if the user selects a "tool" twice w/out selecting a version.  I just want to hide all version selectboxes not associated w/ the tool I just selected.  Thanks.

Comment: Because you need to quote the value within the `not()` (to give `$('select:not("#cgs")').hide();` ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Na9Wq/2/)). Although it's entirely possible that something else in the JavaScript is affecting things somehow (since the [API for `:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) makes no mention, or indication, that quoting is required).

Comment: Thanks David.  I got it to work and quoting was not required.  I'll post the solution in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, I have it solved.  I think my problem has something to do w/ the [Selectmenu plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/).  I started w/ example code and tried to make my code fit w/in it's structure.  I'm sure someone w/ more Javascript experience than I can turn this into fewer lines of code.

Anyway, the secret was to create an ID for the fieldset containing the "tool" selectbox and then call the following code as soon as the tool is selected:

```
$('fieldset:not(#fs-tool, ' + tool + ')').hide();
```

This hides everything except the fieldset and selectbox for the selected tool.

`$('select:not(#tool, ' + tool + ')').hide();` does not work here.

Also, I added "lasttool = tool;" for 1st run through, otherwise multiple version selectboxes will show depending on order in which user selects them.

These two changes allowed other scripts to be removed that made the code verbose.  In the end, I'm not 100% sure why this works but I'm glad it does.  Below is the final Javascript and HTML.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var tool;     //The selected tool
  var version;  //The selected tool version
  var lasttool; //The previously selected tool

  $('select#tool').selectmenu({
    // use select callback
    select: function(event, options) {
      tool = options.value;
      $('select#'+tool).val("none");  //This resets the version selectbox to "Select a version".  Otherwise the last version selected shows and the ".change(function(){..." does not fire.         

      $('fieldset:not(#fs-tool, ' + tool + ')').hide();   //Hide everything except the fieldset and selectbox for the selected tool.
                                                          //"$('select:not(#tool, ' + tool + ')').hide();" does not work here 
      if (tool == "cgs") {  
        lasttool = tool;  //Set lasttool= tool for 1st run through, otherwise multiple version selectboxes will show depending on order in which user selects                     
        $('select#'+tool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();       //Without this, the version selectbox won't show
        $('select#'+lasttool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();   //Hide the last tool version selected
        $('select#'+tool).parent("fieldset").show();  //This shows the version selectbox
        $("#cgs").change(function(){
           version = $(this).val();
           document.getElementById("val_scenarios").innerHTML=(tool + " - " + version);
           lasttool = tool;   //Must keep track to hide later, if needed
         });
      } else if (tool == "dpss"){
        $('select#'+tool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();
        $('select#'+lasttool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();
        $('select#'+tool).parent("fieldset").show();
        $("#dpss").change(function(){
           version = $(this).val();
           document.getElementById("val_scenarios").innerHTML=(tool + " - " + version);
           lasttool = tool;
         });            
      } else if (tool == "elt5500"){
        $('select#'+tool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();
        $('select#'+lasttool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();
        $('select#'+tool).parent("fieldset").show();
        $("#elt5500").change(function(){
           version = $(this).val();
           document.getElementById("val_scenarios").innerHTML=(tool + " - " + version);
           lasttool = tool;
         });  
      } else if (tool == "iapioneer"){  
        $('select#'+tool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();
        $('select#'+lasttool).selectmenu({maxHeight: 150}).parent("fieldset").hide();
        $('select#'+tool).parent("fieldset").show();
        $("#iapioneer").change(function(){
           version = $(this).val();
           document.getElementById("val_scenarios").innerHTML=(tool + " - " + version);
           lasttool = tool;
         });   
      } else {
        $('select#'+lasttool).parent("fieldset").hide();  //Hide the last tool version selectbox when "Select a tool" is selected instead of an actual tool"
        document.getElementById("val_scenarios").innerHTML=("Tool: " + tool + "; Version - " + version + "; Last Tool - " + lasttool);
      } 
    }
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="tb" class="qualifier">
      <form id="info" action="">
        <fieldset id="fs-tool">
          <select name='tool' id='tool'>
            <option value="none" selected>Select a tool...</option>
            <option value="cgs" >CGS/GXP</option> 
            <option value="dpss">DPSS</option> 
            <option value="elt5500">ELT5500</option> 
            <option value="iapioneer">IAPioneer</option>
          </select>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <select id="cgs" name='cgs'> 
            <option value="none" selected>Select a version...</option>
            <option value="cgs_1.0"> CGS 1.0/GXP</option>
            <option value="cgs_1.1"> CGS 1.1/GXP</option>
          </select> 
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset> 
          <select id="dpss" name='dpss'>
            <option value="none" selected>Select a version...</option>
            <option value="dpss_2.0">DPSS 2.0</option>
            <option value="dpss_2.0.7.29">DPSS 2.0.7.29</option>
          </select>           
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
          <select id="elt5500" name='elt5500'>
            <option value="none" selected>Select a version...</option>
            <option value="elt5500_4.0">ELT5500 PRO 4.0/CGS 2.1</option>
            <option value="elt5500_4.1">ELT5500 PRO 4.1/CGS 2.1</option>
          </select> 
        </fieldset>  

        <fieldset>
          <select id="iapioneer" name='iapioneer'>
            <option value="none" selected>Select a version...</option>
            <option value="iapioneer_2.1">IAPioneer/CGS 2.3.1</option>
          </select> 
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="val_scenarios"></div>
```